# linux kernel based programming to update routing table

Tags: linux, routes, kernel

hi i am working on research project in which i have to do update on routing table of system with some conditions. The overall goal is to achieve a secure aodv, already aodv is successfully running on my adhoc network.

Comment: I think you need to elaborate a little bit on your exact requirement. Why and what do you mean by "linux Kernel based" programming? Why don't you use the simple yet handy 'ip route -add' ?

Comment: hi, AODVUU is an open source implementation of a aodv routing protocol which is programmed in c language in linux kernel version 2.4. now i am working on adding security to aodvuu so i want to learn linux kernel programming related to routing/networking,, help me out to get materials.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into http://olsr.org/ for your answer it is also another adhoc routing protocol. They would be modifying routing table through kernel programming.

May I know how did you install AODV in your ad-hoc network. Are you using any open source AODV implementation. If so can you please share it with me. I can find only old AODV implementation for old Linux kernel. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.